# How to send MQTT PINGREQ to server in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt, mosquitto

I am new to mqtt and searching for PINGREQ function format. Please help me about. Thanks.

Comment: Have you even tried to search for the spec?

Comment: ya i tried. but i didn't got the solution

Answer (score 0):

You don't send them manually, the MQTT client library you are using will send a PINGREQ to the broker if it hasn't sent any other messages (e.g. published a message, or acknowledged the receipt of the message) to the broker within the timeout period.

If for some reason you are implementing your own client from scratch then details of the packet formats are in the published MQTT [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718081).